# Combination of large numbers that summed reach an specific value

Tags: python

I have a number X that is a result of a combination of other 353 numbers.

I basically need to find all the possible combinations of the 353 numbers that summed are equal to the specific value of X.

The easiest way to make the combinations I found was the package "combi". However, I couldn't find an easy way to sum the results of the combinations and check if they match the X value other than creating a loop like this:

```
import pandas as pd
from combi import *
x = 5
while x <= 353:
    comb_space = CombSpace(DF2['DADOS'], x)
    y = comb_space.length -1
    while y > 0:
    z = sum(comb_space[y])
        if z < -40000000 and z > -50000000:
            print(z)
        else:
            y -= 1
            print(y)
x += 1
```

DF2 is a data frame containing all the 353 numbers that I mentioned. The problem is that the possible combinations for 353 numbers are HUGE.
Is there a simplest/fastest way to code a solution?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Maybe, you need to post this question in the Maths forums. I think it's related to Set theory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case the choice for each of the parts is binary, i.e. "include or not". The easiest way to enumerate all combination is to count to 2^353, using each of 353 bits as an indicator of inclusion.

As you can see, the number of possible combinations is very high, so solving this problem by brute force isn't really a good approach.

Instead, it is solvable by using dynamic programming. E.g., the number of all possible combinations is the number of combinations if I don't take this number and if I take it.

This can be further improved by introducing bounds. If we sort the numbers and count how many of them we used/discarded and how many we have remaining, we can prune certain branches.

```
def count_combinations(numbers, expected_result, quota=None):
    # first call: sort numbers and cache the sum of remaining elements
    if quota is None:
        quota = sum(numbers)
        numbers.sort()
    if quota < expected_result:  # optimization: prune search
        return 0
    elif quota == expected_result:  # there is only one way to make it
        return 1
    candidate = numbers[-1]
    quota -= candidate
    # count feasible combinations if we don't take the number
    combinations = count_combinations(numbers[:-1], expected_result, quota)
    # add those if we do
    if candidate <= expected_result:
        combinations += count_combinations(numbers[:-1], expected_result - candidate, quota)
    return combinations
```

This does not account for duplicated numbers, but I hope you get the idea.